# When every localization of the polynomial ring over a ring has finitely many idempotents

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, sheaf-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring  such that every  localization ring $R_r$ has finitely many idempotents for each non nilpotent element $r\in R$. Why dose every  localization ring $R[x]_{f(x)}$ have finitely many idempotents for each non nilpotent polynomial $f(x)\in R[x]$?

Comment: By quotient ring $R_r$, do you mean $R/(r)$ or the localization?

Comment: @Asvin: thank you for your comment. It was corrected.